# Attach file manually through Android Studio to internal storage

Tags: android, android-studio, android-file, file-read

I need to attach a file to my android application internal storage, but I do not want to do it by coding. Do you know if there is any shortcut or toolset in Android Studio to attach de file from my computer to the internal storage of my app in order too later be able to read it and edit it from the code??

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at assets directory.

Comment: I think you cannot edit files from there by code

Comment: Indeed. It is only for transport from your development pc to app on Android device. The Android app would then make a copy on file system amd edit that copy. Thats the way that is available.